# parse a NSURL mailto

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing

How can I parse a mailto request ?

```
'mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someone_else@example.com&subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&body=This%20is%20the%20body'
```

From this NSURL, I want to extract the recipient, the subject and the body. How should I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is some code that will parse any URL and return a dictionary with the parameters and the associated objects in a dictionary. It works for `mailto` URLs, too.
Please note: This code assumes you're using **ARC**!

```
@interface NSString (URLDecoding)  

- (NSString *) URLDecodedString;

@end
```

---

```
@implementation NSString (URLDecoding)

- (NSString *) URLDecodedString {
    NSString *result = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)self, CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return result;
}

@end
```

---

```
- (NSDictionary *) parameterDictionaryFromURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSMutableDictionary *parameterDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"mailto"]) {
        NSString *mailtoParameterString = [[url absoluteString] substringFromIndex:[@"mailto:" length]];
        NSUInteger questionMarkLocation = [mailtoParameterString rangeOfString:@"?"].location;
        [parameterDictionary setObject:[mailtoParameterString substringToIndex:questionMarkLocation] forKey:@"recipient"];

        if (questionMarkLocation != NSNotFound) {
            NSString *parameterString = [mailtoParameterString substringFromIndex:questionMarkLocation + 1];
            NSArray *keyValuePairs = [parameterString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
            for (NSString *queryString in keyValuePairs) {
                NSArray *keyValuePair = [queryString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
                if (keyValuePair.count == 2)
                    [parameterDictionary setObject:[[keyValuePair objectAtIndex:1] URLDecodedString] forKey:[[keyValuePair objectAtIndex:0] URLDecodedString]];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        NSString *parameterString = [url parameterString];
        NSArray *keyValuePairs = [parameterString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
        for (NSString *queryString in keyValuePairs) {
            NSArray *keyValuePair = [queryString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            if (keyValuePair.count == 2)
                [parameterDictionary setObject:[[keyValuePair objectAtIndex:1] URLDecodedString] forKey:[[keyValuePair objectAtIndex:0] URLDecodedString]];
        }
    }

    return [parameterDictionary copy];
}
```

---

And here is how you use it:

```
NSURL *mailtoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:foo@example.com?cc=bar@example.com&subject=Greetings%20from%20Cupertino!&body=Wish%20you%20were%20here!"];
NSDictionary *parameterDictionary = [self parameterDictionaryFromURL:mailtoURL];

NSString *recipient = [parameterDictionary objectForKey:@"recipient"];
NSString *subject = [parameterDictionary objectForKey:@"subject"];
NSString *body = [parameterDictionary objectForKey:@"body"];
```

**EDIT:**
I updated the code to work with any URL and recipients are now in the dictionary for `mailto` URLs.

Comment: Very elegant solution. I like the abstraction.

Comment: how can i attach a text file with it?

Comment: This was to get the contents of the query, not attach something to it.

Comment: this does not get the recipient

Comment: As user102008 points out, the recipient isn't actually contained in the query part of the URL.

Comment: Could be a nice NSURL category.

Comment: There is a crash bug in the above code if the mailto: url doesn't contain a "?"

Answer (score 2):

I would pull the email from that like this:

```
NSString * mailToString = @"'mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someone_else@example.com&subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&body=This%20is%20the%20body'";

NSArray *tempArray = [mailToString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];

//get email address from array
NSString * emailString = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:0]description];

//clean up string
emailString = [emailString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'mailto:" withString:@""]; 

//and here is your email string
NSLog(@"%@",emailString);
```

Comment: Using `-description` is very bad practice.

Comment: Why using `-description` is very bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 7 this is easily doable with NSURLComponents. You can create that object with:

```
if let components = NSURLComponents(URL: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL:false) { ...
```

Then you can get the recipient accessing the path property of NSURLComponents; and the parameters with the queryItems property. For instance, if we wanted to get the subject, something like this would do our job

```
let queryItems = components.queryItems as? [NSURLQueryItem]
let subject = queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "subject"}).first?.value
```

Comment: `queryItems` and the `NSURLQueryItem` class itself are only available since iOS 8.0, though.

Answer (score 0):

NSURL category for just mailto:   This method also has a fix for a crash bug in Fabian's answer above when mailto: url doesn't contain a ?.  It also doesn't require the URLDecodedString category method.

```
@implementation NSURL (Additions)

- (NSDictionary *) parameterDictionaryForMailTo {
    NSMutableDictionary *parameterDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString *mailtoParameterString = [[self absoluteString] substringFromIndex:[@"mailto:" length]];
    NSUInteger questionMarkLocation = [mailtoParameterString rangeOfString:@"?"].location;
    if (questionMarkLocation != NSNotFound) {
        [parameterDictionary setObject:[mailtoParameterString substringToIndex:questionMarkLocation] forKey:@"recipient"];
        NSString *parameterString = [mailtoParameterString substringFromIndex:questionMarkLocation + 1];
        NSArray *keyValuePairs = [parameterString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
        for (NSString *queryString in keyValuePairs) {
            NSArray *keyValuePair = [queryString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            if (keyValuePair.count == 2)
                [parameterDictionary setObject:[[keyValuePair objectAtIndex:1] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding] forKey:[[keyValuePair objectAtIndex:0] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding]];
        }
    }
    else {
        [parameterDictionary setObject:mailtoParameterString forKey:@"recipient"];
    }

    return [parameterDictionary copy];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```objectivec
- (NSDictionary *) parameterDictionaryFromURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSMutableDictionary *parameterDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSURLComponents * urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:url.absoluteString];
    for (NSURLQueryItem *item in urlComponents.queryItems) {
        parameterDictionary[item.name] = item.value;
    }
    if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"mailto"]) {
        NSUInteger questionMarkLocation = [url.resourceSpecifier rangeOfString:@"?"].location;
        if (questionMarkLocation == NSNotFound) {
            parameterDictionary[@"recipient"] = url.resourceSpecifier;
        } else {
            parameterDictionary[@"recipient"] = [url.resourceSpecifier substringToIndex:questionMarkLocation];
        }
    }
    return [parameterDictionary copy];
}
```